# How can I log the origin of my Hibernate queries?

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x

I'm trying to gather some statistics on my hibernate/JPA usage. I've deployed Jboss-AS 7.1.1.Final with Hibernate-4.1.8, which is used in a JSF2 project.

I know I can get overall stats via Hibernate's Statistics MBean (enabled via `hibernate.generate_statistics` in `persistence.xml`)

But I'm trying to pin down where my Hibernate queries originate. So I think I need to listen to `load` [events](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-events), but I'm unsure how I'd go about obtaining the method that caused the event. I guess I need the name of the top-most method in the stack that does not belong to the `org.hibernate` package, then?

Can somebody help or suggest a more appropriate way?

Answer (score 0):

If what you are after is a way to track down the source of long running queries, you might consider using SQL comments.  Hibernate allows embedding of comments into the SQL statements sent to the database.  So if you see a query that is taking a lot of time/resources on your database you can use these comments to help track them down.  When enabled, Hibernate  will automatically add comments for any of the static SQL it generates (aka, not native SQL queries, HQL/JPQL queries ot criteria queries).  So for example, the SQL for session.load( Person.class, 1 ) would include a comment like "Loading Person"

Even queries can be assigned a comment using org.hibernate.Query#setComment (or the "org.hibernate.comment" hint with JPA).

But if you really want to track it the way you suggest, then I don't really see an option aside from stack trace hackery.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. But yeah, I'm after the callsite b/c I want to track down inefficencies in my mapping and it's use by my service layer. So the idea was that I'd record which class causes which kind of queries to find pain points and then work out if these calls are really needed. I've got the nagging feeling I'm reloading entities way too often.

Comment: My point was that that would be easier if you first knew which queries were being performed more often than expected...